# Derive column values from other columns using a stored procedure in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to concatenate values from two columns and put it in the third column using a stored procedure. But I'm getting error.

This is my stored procedure:

```
create proc deriveColumn_SP
    @col_1 varchar(20),
    @col_2 varchar(20)
as
begin
    insert into tableName(col_5)
    values concat(@col_1, @col_2)
end
```

I get an error message that reads

> Incorrect syntax near 'concat'

I want the derived value to be in `col_1_value, col_2_value` format. Data type of all the columns are `varchar` (`varchar(50)` for `col_5`).

Please help

Comment: thanks @marc_s I've made that change

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into tableName(col_5)
values (concat(@col_1, @col_2))
```

or just use a `select`

```
insert into tableName(col_5)
select concat(@col_1, @col_2)
```